# Error during compilation of the code using make file in VC++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am using below snippet in my code.

```
//from Vista WinNT.h
// 
typedef struct _TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL {
SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Label;
} TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL, *PTOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL;
```

When I build this through VS2005  it give no error. But when I am building using make file i am getting below error in cmd:

> Test.cpp(337) : error C2011: '_TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL' : 'struct' type redefinition
>           C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\include\winnt.h(7351) : see declaration of '_TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL'

I am using Opus software to use make file. Please let me know if I am missing something or needs to add some libs to overcome this error.

Comment: Why do you have that in your code? As the error indicates, it's already defined in `Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\include\winnt.h`, which make apparently can find. Remove the typedef from your code and fix your include directories in VS2005.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for response but I am not able to understand why it doesn't flag error when we use VS2005 development environment. But when we use make file why it shows error. I am working on the code that is written by others so not sure why it was written here even it is present in make file.

Comment: It seems like VS2005 hasn't got the include path configured, where make in some way does get the include path.

Comment: Never copy SDK declarations.  High time to update your tools, 10 years is 3 dog lives in software engineering.

Comment: @HansPassant I have removed the declaration of sDK from my code and used #include <WinNT.h>, but now the error I am getting is 'PTOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL' : undeclared identifier.